# Power BI embedded with MFA (app owns data)

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded

I have a Power BI embedded application (app owns data) and I'm having an issue with Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication for a user account that uses multi-factor authentication (MFA). My code works fine for users without MFA. Is there a way to disable MFA for that scenario? App passwords don't work.

Answer (score 0):

MFA configuration is not controlled by PowerBI, you can disable MFA requirement for your master user following the steps described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates

Comment: MFA is not enabled on this page and yet i'm receiving this message : Error retrieving Access token
AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Azure is so unfriendly